# Create equivalent of Androids sync adapter on iOS

Tags: ios, background, adapter, synchronization, account

I got data on a webserver which I want to download to an iOS contact list. Is it possible to programatically create an account on iOS that works like the android "sync adapter" and is not one of the default account or an LDAP/CardDAV account?

Or can I have my application to periodically chech for updates on my webserver without the user having to manually start it. (i.e. running in the background and starting up automatically when the phone is restarted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, to both. The best you can do is create a [configuration profile](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html) that the user can download to add an LDAP/CardDAV account—but you will need to run an actual LDAP or CardDAV server to have any kind of automatic contact syncing happen without the user opening your app. The Address Book framework on iOS only allows you to add and modify contacts within the existing accounts on the device, and the [multitasking rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24) only allow your app to start in the background if it provides a VoIP service.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**silverstripe-sync**](https://github.com/markguinn/silverstripe-sync) !

Source: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981812/sync-adapter-on-ios-my-app-sync-contact-with-my-server)