# Sync adapter on IOS - My app sync contact with my server

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, carddav

I have an application that make JSON request and recover some contacts from db . But now, sync my app with my server. For example : sync all contacts from my db and register it into my address book (in my device). Like in android sync adapter. 
It is possible in android ?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/markguinn/silverstripe-sync . It might help.