# How to automatically recognise internet connection using Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, offline, data-synchronization, offline-mode

I want to synchronize data with my App-Server whenever data has been saved to the local database (sqlite) on my mobile phone. I need a mechanism that automatically detects an internet connection in order to send the related saved data to my server at any time. 
That's how I want to realize an offline mode.

Which approaches can you recommend me? Are there any frameworks which do that job? In android I use syncAdapter, does Swift3 provides a similar framework or do I need to create an own solution?

Comment: `SCNetworkReachability` can be used to detect status and changes of the network connectivity. https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift is a well-known Swift wrapper. You'll also find many Q&A about SCNetworkReachability here on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sync adapter on IOS - My app sync contact with my server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981812/sync-adapter-on-ios-my-app-sync-contact-with-my-server)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create equivalent of Androids sync adapter on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406736/create-equivalent-of-androids-sync-adapter-on-ios)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or OSX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-ios-or-osx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to do it-

1. Use pod 'ReachabilitySwift' in your pod file
2. In 'AppDelegate' import ReachabilitySwift
3. Write following code in AppDelegate

   ```
    var reachabilityManager:ReachabilityManager = ReachabilityManager.sharedInstance
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.shared.isEnabled = true
       reachabilityManager.initRechabilityMonitor()
       return true
   }

   func reachabilityStatusChangeHandler(_ reachability: Reachability) {
       if reachability.isReachable {
           print("isReachable")
       } else {
           print("notReachable")
       }
   }
   ```